# Iterating and Invoking text from element retrieves all the text from all the same elements in Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm currently trying to iterate through a list of divs each div having the same id. Within each div I want to retrieve some text for that specific div, but instead, it is returning the text from all the labels in each div. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<div id='some_id'><span id='day'>Mon</span></div>
<div id='some_id'><span id='day'>Tue</span></div>
<div id='some_id'><span id='day'>Wed</span></div>
<div id='some_id'><span id='day'>Thu</span></div>

</ul>
```

**Cypress**

This is what I am trying to do to get the text:

```
    cy.get('#day')
    .invoke('text')
    .then(($label) => {
        const day = $label;
    });
```

Returns:

```
day = MonTueWedThu
```

To iterate through the divs I have this but is not working:

```
cy.get(#some_id).each( ($row) => {
  cy.wrap($row)
       .find('#day')
       .invoke('text')
       .then(($label) => {
           const day = $label;
        });

});
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the text from one of the elements or each of the elements? What are your plans for the extracted text?

Comment: I want to use the variable for that specific day and and use it within the same iteration. So basically, I have a command that I want to use for each day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the `#day` elements to the innerText property, something like

```js
cy.get('#day')
  .then($els => [...$els].map(el => el.innerText))
  .should('deep.eq', ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu'])
```